# Use regular expression to evaluate and modify string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to modify part of a string I have using Ruby.

The string is `[x, y]` where `y` is an integer that I want to change to its alphabetical letter.  So say `[1, 1]` would become `[1, A]` and `[1, 26]` would become `[1, Z]`.

Would a regular expression help me do this? or is there an easier way? I am not to strong with regular expressions, I am reading up on those now.

Comment: Looks like you have a string where you should have a tuple?

Comment: Well what I am doing is changing an index I have for excel cells. The gem I am using gives me the index as [1, 1], etc.  I just want to change that to the column formats [1, A]

Comment: MS Excel can handle that: choose Tools->Options->General tab-> R1C1 reference style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of is the following

```
string = "[1,1]"
array = string.chop.reverse.chop.reverse.split(',')
new_string="[#{array.first},#{(array.last.to_i+64).chr}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

Because we do not have an alphabet yet we can look up the position, create one.
This is a range converted to an array so you don't need to specify it yourself.

```
alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a
```

Then we try to get the integer/position out of the string:

```
string_to_match = "[1,5]"
/(\d+)\]$/.match(string_to_match)
```

Maybe the regexp can be improved, however for this example it is working.
The first reference in the MatchData is holding the second integer in your "string_to_match".
Or you can get it via "$1".
Do not forget to convert it to an integer.

```
position_in_alphabet = $1.to_i
```

Also we need to remember that the index of arrays starts at 0 and not 1

```
position_in_alphabet -= 1
```

Finally, we can take a look which char we really get

```
char = alphabet[position_in_alphabet]
```

Example:

```
alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a #=> ["A", "B", "C", ..*snip*.. "Y", "Z"]
string_to_match = "[1,5]" #=> "[1,5]"
/(\d+)\]$/.match(string_to_match) #=> #<MatchData "5]" 1:"5">
position_in_alphabet = $1.to_i #=> 5
position_in_alphabet -= 1 #=> 4
char = alphabet[position_in_alphabet] #=> "E"
```

Greetings~